# How does the Federal Reserve insure there is no conflict of interest or minimize the conflict of interest within the organization?

Tags: united-states, federal-reserve, conflict-of-interest

> “This report reveals the inherent conflicts of interest that exist at
> the Federal Reserve,” said Sanders in a statement. “At a time when
> small businesses could not get affordable loans to create jobs, the
> Fed was providing trillions in [then] secret loans to some of the
> largest banks and corporations in America that were well represented
> on the boards of the Federal Reserve Banks. These conflicts must end.”

https://www.huffpost.com/entry/federal-reserve-directors-conflicts-bernie-sanders_n_1594291

How does the Federal Reserve insure there is no conflict of interest or minimize the conflict of interest within the organization? I am wondering this, because a lot of the board members seem to come from the private sector, so I am wondering how the organization insures that the board members don't just pocket money for themselves. Is there any mechanism or rule that seeks to combat this?

Comment: I'm not totally sure about the context here.  Your quote says "There is a conflict of interest" but your question asks "Why is there no conflict of interest".

Comment: @JamesK the question asks what they do the combat COI, not that there is none.